# Tethering issues on OnePlus 6T (not operator related)

Tags: wifi-hotspot, tethering, usb-tethering

My 6T (unrooted) Android 10.3.5, won't tether - not by USB, not by Wifi nor by Bluetooth.

Not a carrier issue - I can tether with my wife's phone.

Weird behaviour - occasionally the tethered device (PC) will have internet, but not the phone, sometimes the phone will have internet and not the tethered device.

I have AdGuard and NordVPN installed, but I turn them both off before trying to tether.

I have disabled Private DNS before trying to tether.

Doesn't work in Safe mode either. Shows connected device to hotspot on phone.

If I connect the phone to Wifi then the PC has internet and the phone does also - not very helpful.

It used to tether months ago.

Any ideas please?

Comment: See routing table (using `ip`) and firewall (using `iptables`) when tethering turned on. The simple way to troubleshoot networking issues. Latter requires root.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you happen to have any battery optimizations enabled, or any installed apps that purport to make your battery life more efficient?

Comment: No battery optimization apps - OnePlus is aggressive enough without help and offers good controls.  FYI - I found the answer below - thanks for your interest @czarmatt

Comment: @IrfanLatif  Thanks, I made a note of that tool for the future

Answer (score 0):

Editing the APN didn't help.
Recreating a new APN from scratch resolved the issue - even though they look identical to me on the screen.
Leaving here for others to hopefully benefit.